# Is there built-in data structure in clojure supporting both duplicated elements and O(1) removing?

Tags: data-structures, clojure

Recently, I need to implement a special set in clojure which may have duplicated elements (i.e. a multiset), like

```
#{1 2 3 4 1 2}
```

what's more, removing an arbitrary element equal to the assigned value in O(1) time is needed as well. For example, when I type

```
(my-remove #{1 1 2 2 3 4} 2)
```

it should return `#{1 1 2 3 4}` without loop through the whole set(or vector).

My question is, is there a built-in data structure in clojure satisfying these two properties. If not, is there any proper alternative solution to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Clojure lacks a standard multiset/bag. You could try [this](https://github.com/achim/multiset) - untested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A map of values to their "count" ? (Removing a value would be decreasing the counter ?)

Comment: Thanks！But is there an intuitive way to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "intuitive" ; this data structure is not supported by default, so you'll definitively have to "wrap" a standard hash-map, and write you own contains / add / remove functions. This seems to be done in the multiset lib mentionned by @Thumbnail.

Comment: I took a look at the multiset on github just now. You're right... I have few experience with clojure programming, and this solution seems to be the most feasible ones, I think. Anyway, thanks for the explanation!